# How can I get types of a morph in polymorphic many to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have three tables - Medias, Cities and Genres. The relationship between them is Many To Many (polymorphic). A City has many Medias. A Genre also has many medias and vise versa.

```
Cities
  id, name

Genres
  id, name

Medias
  id, name

Mediaable
  id, mediaable_id, mediaable_type
```

I want to get all Medias with theirs mediaable types :

```
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Media {#1128 ▼
         [
       "id" => 1,
       'name'=>'foo.png',
       "types" => ['City', 'Genre']
  ],

   1 => App\Models\Media {#1128 ▼
        [
       "id" => 1,
       'name'=>'foo.png',
       "types" => ['City']
   ],

    2 => App\Models\Media {#1128 ▼
        [
       "id" => 1,
       'name'=>'foo.png',
       "types" => []
   ],
];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: @Elias I  have no idea

Comment: I have to agree with Elias here. You cant just post a question, with minimal effort, and then expect others to resolve your issue out of the blue. I would advice studying this article really well: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Well, good luck with that :)

Comment: It's not a bad question, but I need to clarify if a `Media` can have more than one `City` and more than one `Genre`?

Comment: @Azeame Yes it's many to many relationship and a Media can have more than one City and Genre

Comment: Okay, so the next question is: a) do you not know how to retrieve a Media's relationships from the database, b) is the issue wanting to only return the mediaable_types as types without returning the full relationship data, or c) you don't know how to do either of those?

Comment: @Azeame, I have a website with 3 pages: cities, genres and medias, a media can be used with multiple genres and cities,  in medias page under the each media title I want to display media types used for, for example:  'city,genre' or 'city' or 'genre' or empty string, I am seeking for medias page API

Comment: Thank you, that makes your question much clearer. Final question, when you say `city,genre` do you actually mean those words or do you mean the actual name of the city and genre say `Johannesburg, Hotel`

Comment: I went ahead and answered it any, feel free to comment/edit the answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `\App\Models\Medias::class` with the following relationships:

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('Cities', 'mediaables');
}

public function genres()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('Genres', 'mediaables');
}

public function medias()
{
    return $this->morphByMany();
}
```

Then you can use the following:

```
public function getTypesAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->medias->each(function($media)
        {
            return class_basename($media);
        })
        ->unique() // Use this if you never want to besure you only get one City
        ->implode(', ');
}
```

If you only want the base `Model` class names then you can use the following:

```
public function getTypesAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->medias->each(function($media)
        {
            return class_basename($media);
        })
        ->unique() // Use this to ensure City or Genre only appears once
        ->implode(', ');
}
```

If you need the names of the cities and genres from the database then I'd use the following:

```
public function getTypesAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->medias->pluck('name') // 'name' only works if every 'mediaable_type' model has a 'name' attribute
        ->unique() // Optional
        ->implode(', ');
}
```

This way when you are returning your API data, then you call use `$media->types` to get what you need.